# New Rotor making noise after installation

Tags: noise, subaru, brake-rotor, outback

Replaced rear rotors, calipers, pads, hardware.  One wheel was making noise as I test drove it.  I found the rotor had some scratches closer to the inside but other than the pad I couldn't find what might be scraping it.

So, I moved the rotor and pads to the other wheel.  The sound moved as well.  Then I swapped rotors again and the noise moved. I put in the old rotor and no noise.  So it is definitely something up with the rotor.  I am currently concluding that the rotor is defective, but wanted to know if anyone had any other theories or anything else I can check.

2007 Subaru Outback XT

Answer (score 1):

Where did you buy the rotors? They could have been sitting for a while. Sometimes when you buy rotors from a discount auto parts store it is a really good idea to have them shaved a little first. Especially the cheaper brands.

Comment: It was a premium rotor (black hat tops), it is possible it could have been sitting for a while, but I think unlikely.

Comment: Your best course of action at this point then would try and return them for new ones. Its clear from the issues you are having the rotor wasn't machined right when produced.